# Reactjs + redux : Sharing reducers across different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am basically trying to create a react webapp with lot of pages. And the data for each page is loaded through different API calls. And most response have information dependent on each other. I decided to use redux to store these response and access from each components.

This is what my reducer file look like,

```
var initialState = {
      "userDetails": [],
      "userPicks": []
    };

module.exports = function(state, action, data) {
  state = state || initialState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_USER_LIST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        "userDetails": action.data
      })

    case 'ADD_USER_PICK_LIST':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        "userPicks": action.data
      })

    case 'UPDATE_SELECTION':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        return "do something"
      });

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So I use

`var redux = require('redux');
var reducers = require('./reducers');
var store = redux.createStore(reducers);`

on top of each component that uses information from store.

```
store.getState()
```

but this process always resets my reducer state to initial one and the app loses all data. Can anyone point out where I am wrong and what I should be looking in to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Can anyone point out where I am wrong " you are creating new store for every component type. You need to make it a separate module and create store once per application.

```
// redux/store js
var redux = require('redux');
var reducers = require('./reducers');
module.exports = redux.createStore(reducers);
```

"what I should be looking in to" you should take a look at official react binding for redux. [React Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

```
// app.js
var store = require('./redux/store.js');
var Provider = require('react-redux').Provider

ReactDOM.render(
 (<Provider store={store}>
     <App />
  </Provider
 ), mountingPoint)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create redux store once in your toplevel app

```
var redux = require('redux');
var reducers = require('./reducers');
var store = redux.createStore(reducers);
```

Dont create for every compnent.
Use container components to mapStatetoProps and mapDispatchToProps and pass props to the components